# Equispacing of error bars in semilogx plot

Tags: matplotlib, errorbar

When I plot using `errorbar` of `matplotlib`, I use the `errorevery` option to avoid crowding the error bars. However, if x-axis is set to log scale, then the error bars do not look equispaced anymore.

```
N = 40
xdata = np.arange(N)+1
ydata = (xdata/N)**2
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.errorbar(xdata, ydata, yerr=0.1*np.ones(N), errorevery=4, elinewidth=0.5, ecolor='r')
ax.set_xscale("log")
```

[image]

Is there a way to keep the visual equispacing on log scale, which might look like the following (drawn roughly):

[image]

Comment: Pass in data that is logarithmically distributed in x?

Comment: But then the x-ticks will not be in exponential form.

Comment: `xdata = np.logspace(1, 2, 20); ydata = (xdata/N)**2`

Comment: oh that is clever. but I cannot do that, because I have some data where `xdata` must be each and every integer between `1` and `N`. So, I cannot change `xdata = np.arange(N)+1`.

Comment: in other words, `xdata` is an integer field, say like year and I have `ydata` and its standard deviation (which appears as error bar in form 3*sigma) for every year. I just replaced that with `xdata**2` and `ones` for simplicity

Comment: So your data is linearly spaced in x, but you want to plot logarithmically, but have the error bars spaced linearly.  You can space the indices logarithmically, but there will be round off errors.  You might also consider using fill_betweenx to put a halo around your data.

Comment: Thanks for the input @JodyKlymak I will keep that in mind when I return to this project

Comment: fill_between option worked well. Thanks @JodyKlymak